# Insert line breaks in hidden fields value

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about inserting line breaks in the value of hidden fields?

For ex. this is how my hidden field looks like:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="dahidden" value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> <%=da.getEmail() %> <%=da.getPhone() %> <%=da.getExt() %>">
```

I need to insert line breaks after `da.getLname()` and `da.getEmail()`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the line breaks directly. They are permitted within attributes.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="dahidden" value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %>

 <%=da.getEmail() %> <%=da.getPhone() %> <%=da.getExt() %>">
```

Comment: So, I tried this <input type="hidden" name="dahidden" value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> <br> <%=da.getEmail() %> <br> <%=da.getPhone() %> <%=da.getExt() %>"> But with this, I'm getting something like ABC <br> labc.org <br> 123-456-7888 And not getting the actual line breaks

Comment: @Pritish - What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Not _how_, but the _end result_?

Comment: This is true, but you also need to make sure to escape the double quote marks! The example here is broken.